# Strange Popup in Browser

Tags: macos, web-browser, url

Does anyone knows what is this, where it comes from and how to fix it? It shows up randomly and rare.

[image]

URL:
`data:text/html;base64,PG1ldGEvaHR0cC1lcXVpdj1yZWZyZXNoIGNvbnRlbnQ9MDt1cmw9aHR0cDovL2FkY2xpY2suZy5kb3VibGVjbGljay5uZXQvcGNzL2NsaWNrP2FkdXJsPWh0dHBzJTNBJTJGJTJGc2VydmljZW9wZXJhdGl2ZS5jb20lMkZwYWdlJTJGJTNGZnh0NENYWHI4OUJmVXdjVUdUSjRiNlVERD4=.`

Comment: It would be easier to diagnose this if you posted the error as copiable text.

Comment: URL data:text/html;base64,PG1ldGEvaHR0cC1lcXVpdj1yZWZyZXNoIGNvbnRlbnQ9MDt1cmw9aHR0cDovL2FkY2xpY2suZy5kb3VibGVjbGljay5uZXQvcGNzL2NsaWNrP2FkdXJsPWh0dHBzJTNBJTJGJTJGc2VydmljZW9wZXJhdGl2ZS5jb20lMkZwYWdlJTJGJTNGZnh0NENYWHI4OUJmVXdjVUdUSjRiNlVERD4=.

Comment: The base-64 decodes to `<meta/http-equiv=refresh content=0;url=http://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?adurl=https%3A%2F%2Fserviceoperative.com%2Fpage%2F%3Ffxt4CXXr89BfUwcUGTJ4b6UDD>`. Looks like a website/extension is trying to open a page in the background, but instead of directing to a URL, they've mangled their code such that it tries to direct you to a `meta` tag (an invalid URL) instead.

Comment: @aaplmath in english please, whom do I kill

Comment: @aaplmath Which decodes to `http://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?adurl=https://serviceoperative.com/page/?fxt4CXXr89BfUwcUGTJ4b6UDD`

Comment: @JBis Precisely. Which leads me to think that it’s a slightly dubious website or browser extension (probably the former) trying to open ads in the background.

Comment: @aaplmath OMG. Wanna laugh. See my answer in a second.

Answer (score 2):

Are you navigating the same site when this appears?
Is it a sketchy one?

If so, it is most likely a failed scammer ad.

Solution: Don't navigate that page anymore.

If not, then it is most likely an extension. To remove follow these instructions:  [Install and manage Safari extensions on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203051) or

1. Go to Safari > Preferences > Extensions
2. Click extension on left
3. Click the uninstall button below the Extension name on the right box
4. Repeat for all extensions

---

Other information:

As stated in the comments:

```
data:text/html;base64,PG1ldGEvaHR0cC1lcXVpdj1yZWZyZXNoIGNvbnRlbnQ9MDt1cmw9aHR0cDovL2FkY2xpY2suZy5kb3VibGVjbGljay5uZXQvcGNzL2NsaWNrP2FkdXJsPWh0dHBzJTNBJTJGJTJGc2VydmljZW9wZXJhdGl2ZS5jb20lMkZwYWdlJTJGJTNGZnh0NENYWHI4OUJmVXdjVUdUSjRiNlVERD4=.
```

is in base64 and decodes to

```
<meta/http-equiv=refresh content=0;url=http://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?adurl=https%3A%2F%2Fserviceoperative.com%2Fpage%2F%3Ffxt4CXXr89BfUwcUGTJ4b6UDD>
```

The `meta/http-equiv=refresh content=0` tells the browser to redirect the following url in `0` seconds (immediately).

The link further decodes (url decode) to

```
http://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?adurl=https://serviceoperative.com/page/?fxt4CXXr89BfUwcUGTJ4b6UDD
```

This is obviously an ad service. `https://serviceoperative.com` is most likely who is gaining $$ from link views. `adclick.g.doubleclick.net` is an ad service usually used by sketchy sites.

Both:

`http://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?adurl=https://serviceoperative.com/page/?fxt4CXXr89BfUwcUGTJ4b6UDD`

and `https://serviceoperative.com/page/?fxt4CXXr89BfUwcUGTJ4b6UDD`

redirect to google.com

---

Sidenote:

`https://serviceoperative.com` has got to have the worst security practices know to earth.

Their homepage requires a login by using CSS to blur the background and prompt for a login:

[image]

The CSS specifically is

```
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-filter;-webkit-transition-duration: .4s;
```

By deleting the CSS and the login page from Inspect Element you can bypass the entire login system, which, of course I did.

Here are the peoples homepage that are trying to make money of scamming innocent people.

[image]

Seems to be some kind of database of all ads.  Gonna give the company and a quick chat.

Comment: Wow.  I’d have answered the OP browser is going to shite web pages or has a compromised plug in / hostile network operator. I hope you have disinfectant for your browser after visiting those sites.

Comment: @bmike Lol. Prob not the smartest thing. If anything more serious probably would have done in a VM, but I find crap like this is more annoying than harmful. XD

Comment: I do not use Safari. It was in Firefox.

Comment: @Buscar웃  will edit tomorrow but same difference remove extensions or bad site